# using replace() or replaceall()

Tags: java, regex

I know of using this:

```
public String RemoveTag(String html){
    html = html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
    html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;","");
    html = html.replaceAll("&amp;","");
    return html;
}
```

This removes all tags within an html string. However the question is how does it get a wild characters in between `<.*?>`. Could someone give me a more detailed explanation on how getting wild characters in String.

The main reason for this is that I still have this characters that has "an @ at start point  and } at end point" and I want to get rid of everything in between `"@"` and `"}"`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking; can you provide short example input and desired output examples?

Comment: Are you asking how do regular expressions work behind the scenes?

Comment: wild card character is inserting automatically or what u r asking ?

Comment: @amit yes I am asking a quick question on how it works on behind the scene for  learning purposes and for the purpose removing characters in between @ and }. Hope that answers your question :).

Comment: @Android Killer What I meant about wild characters is the character between (items ) or <items> where "items" being anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to replaceAll(...) is a regex string. The `.*?` in your example is the part that matches anything. So, if you want a regular expression that will get rid of everything between "@" and "}" you would use something like:

```
String exampleText = "Start @some text} finish.";
exampleText.replaceAll("@(.*?)\\}", "@}");
System.out.println(exampleText); // prints "Start @} finish."
```

Notice the same pattern: `.*?`. The parentheses, which are optional here, are just used for grouping. Also notice the `}` is escaped with backslashes since it can have special meaning within regular expressions.

For more info on Java's regex support see the [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: quick question: what are the \\ for?

Comment: @Akyllite: it is for 'breaking' the `}`, so the regex will take is as a simple character without its 'special meaning', but for `}` it is not needed if you don't have the preceding `{` in your regex.

Comment: I see thank you would like to add accepted answer to 2 guys but can't :(

Answer (score 2):

regular expressions can be implemented by building a [finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), since every regular expression has a finite deterministic automaton and vice versa.

The regex for what you are seeking is `@.*?}` if you want to keep these chars: you can replace it with `"@}"` instead of with `""`. it will be something like: `s.replaceAll("@.*?}", "@}")` [`s` is your String].

It seems you might need the regex "@.*?\}", though the special `}` char should be ignored by the pattern recognizer when it fails to see the preceding `{`. To be on the safe side: `"@.*?\\}"` should work either way, as @WayneBaylor posted.

You might want to read [more on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on wikipedia. I learned a lot. However when testing out the code: "html = html.replaceAll("@.*?}", "");"
It gave me this error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{epub.test/epub.test.EpubReadActivity}: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 5:
 @.*?}

Comment: Wayne Fixed it with "exampleText.replaceAll("@(.*?)\\}", "@}");" thanks